# What malware inserts a .htaccess redirect to Adf.ly?

Tags: hacking, malware

I am hosting a few websites for customers, and a bunch of them have been hacked today. The hack consists of a simple .htaccess file that redirects to adf.ly.

This is the second time I have been affected by this. What malware does this?

Comment: I could imagine an entire book about how to secure your servers from hacking.

Comment: A vulnerable WP site can gain access to other sites depending on the situation. Do not make any assumptions. Update all software. Run anti-virus on all your hard drives including rootkit. And clean any database you have and change all user passwords to strong passwords all-mass. Also, if you run FTP on any of these servers, move it to another server and use ACLs and make it strong. Do not run your own externally available DNS server especially on a web server.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks a lot for reminding me why I usually stay away from Stackexchange sites.

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks for actually taking the time to provide me with something I can use

Comment: @StephenOstermiller is very right about how vast this question is, however, I suppose that a good catch-all (lack of a better term) answer(s) should exist if it does not. There are some standard things to do and some understandings that should be stated. If an answer does not exist, I would happy to help start one and others can chime in. That way, people can at least find a good starting point when they really need help.

Comment: I have a specific issue with malware that puts an .htaccess file in the web root that does a 301 redirect to adf.ly. How much more specific can I get? My assumption was that perhaps others had encountered the same hack. If that is not the case, then I will have to do my own investigation, and I will report my findings back here if any

Comment: I have edited out the parts of your question that ask how to protect your server from malware and focus just on identifying this particular one.

Comment: Can you provide any additional information such as the exact code that it inserts into the .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes. Your question is specific, but the possibilities of *how* you were hacked is vast. Please do not get discouraged. This is a good site with some real experts here. For what it is worth, WP is the most hacked software period and has been for a long time. This is not to say that WP is bad in any respect. Quite the contrary. It is it's popularity and potential for success that makes it the #1 target. So generally, any site that has been hacked that has WP should look there first. Also, there are bonafide viruses that use software that may not be vulnerable.

Comment: Here is a link: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hacked-adfly-and-linkbucks This may not answer your question, but I like the first response. It also reminded me that WP plug-ins can be vulnerable too.

Comment: Also, it appears that themes can be vulnerable too. It appears that you are not alone. Here is an old post: http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/ This may help.

Comment: Also, check for new user accounts and validate them. Force a new password that you create. Do not prompt for a password change since hackers can simply change their own password. Make sure that you run an anti-virus immediately. It appears that some WP/Adf.ly hacks can install a virus to gain access to other sites/systems. It may be that a hacker has been walking around your network for a while. It also appears that vBulletin has been hacked this way where adf.ly redirects in .htaccess appear.

Comment: Here is a link for WP security tools/plugins: http://www.yibbiy.com/10-best-wordpress-security-plugin-2014/

Comment: On a quick side-note, if the .htaccess is not updated automatically by your site, you can set the permissions so that only one or two users has write/modify access to that file for a period. Also, you can change the file used in Apache from .htaccess to something else. You may need to change the config file for this. This may stop the bleeding. Please take notes on the original settings just in case. You may have to experiment with this a bit.

Comment: If you are hosting many clients you most definitely want to set up a cage/jail as well as an app layer firewall to attempt to prevent these cross account (or cross file sys) file drops from occurring. Often this "XFD" happens on shared servers run by poor quality hosts. An under-regulated permissions->account schema for automation is an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: I am afraid I am the poor quality host in this case. Granted, I am not the one who set up the server, but I am currently responsible, so I need to find a good solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any specific identified malware that can be attributed to for this attack, however this kind of behaviour is not uncommon from malicious code inserted into third-party plugins for popular CMS's such as WordPress. People download and install these plugins for the advertised features they offer to sometimes later find that the plugins had been adapted from their original state, and malicious code inserted giving attackers the ability to take over your website. Since redirectly all your visitors to *adf.ly* generates a revenue stream for them it fuels the creation of more and more adapted or patched plug-ins.

How to avoid this?

1. Only download third party plugins from *trusted* websites, i.e. the official WordPress repository, or directly from the vendor's website for premium third party plugins.
2. Check through the source code of any third party plugins before you install them to ensure malicious code has not been inserted. To help, try searching for *add_action*, *base64_decode*, *curl_exec*, *eval*, *gzinflate*, *mail*, *set_role*, *wp_create_user*, *wp_mail*. Use of these does not necessarily mean malicious intent but could warrant closer inspection of the source code.
3. Regularly check your web server software and CMS software is kept patched up-to-date to ensure your website is protected from known vulnerabilities.

Suggested reading: [Securi Blog - Unmasking Free Premium WordPress Plugins](http://blog.sucuri.net/2014/03/unmasking-free-premium-wordpress-plugins.html)

Comment: Very good advice. WP is the most hacked software period for a reason. It is not that WP is bad. In fact, it is quite the opposite. Because of it's popularity and the availability of so many plug-in and *themes* (let's not forget themes) that can all be vulnerable along with any changes to WP, it has become the #1 target. As a result, any WP site owner has to work that much harder to make sure their site is not vulnerable. One up-vote. BTW- I would am curious to hear how the OP is getting along on this. I would like to hear good news.

Comment: Been sick for a couple of days. Thanks a lot for all the input in this thread.

Comment: It was quite easy to fix the issue by simply removing the .htaccess files that redirected to adf.ly. However, I am still not any closer to figuring out where the hack came from in the first place. Ideally, I would look through all the WP sites on our server to look for clues, but that is such a time consuming process, and I have a hard time finding the time for that at the moment.

Comment: One of my tricks is to maintain a database table of genuine published and end-user intended page URLs for a website, and then I have an hourly cron script that analyses the last hour's worth of HTTP traffic in the access_log and error_log files often found in /var/logs/httpd/ (depends where you configure them to be in httpd.conf), ignoring any lines where the requested URLs have an entry in the database, and emailing me with the information available from the log entry for any unrecognised URLs, and a link in the email allows me to quickly whitelist the URL if appropriate.

Comment: Maldet antivirus software is very good and quick at picking up possible malware code on a website so a lot of hosting providers will run Maldet once a day across all their servers. Software developer and use any encryption or obfuscation to try and protect their source code from reverse engineering and human readability will often find their code gets quarantined by Maldet the day after installation, unless the hosting provider white-lists that particular folder or files affected. Installing Maldet may help prevent malware infections from spreading quickly on your server.